# How to filter the rows that have at least one column greater than a threshold?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a data

```
Name    Clust1     Clust2     Clust3
AA    0.0662421  0.01742827 0.02286026
BB    0.7694628  0.03241972 0.02935754
CC    0.1099033  0.52170750 0.28385905
DD    0.2769453  0.30376152 0.24822205
```

I would like to filter the rows that have at least one column greater than 0.50.

I am trying the following command:

`new.df <- df %>% mutate(confident = ifelse(rowSums(.[,c(1:4)] >= 0.5)>0, 'yes', 'no'))`

I am getting the following warning without any output:

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
```

I wish to the following data frame:

```
    Name    Clust1     Clust2     Clust3
    BB    0.7694628  0.03241972 0.02935754
    CC    0.1099033  0.52170750 0.28385905
```

Do you have how can I fix my code to get the desired output. 
Thanks

Comment: `c(1:4)` - you're trying to do a numeric calculation including column `1`, which are your names. Try `c(2:4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` directly

```
df[rowSums(df[2:4] >= 0.5) > 0, ]

#  Name  Clust1  Clust2   Clust3
#2   BB 0.76946 0.03242 0.029358
#3   CC 0.10990 0.52171 0.283859
```

---

Or `dplyr` version with `filter_at` and `any_vars`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Clust")), any_vars(. >= 0.5))
```

and as far as fixing your code is concerned as mentioned by @thelatemail you are including column 1 in `rowSums` which is the `Name` column, so you want to subset it on columns `2:4`. Also we can directly `filter` instead of creating new variable with `mutate`, so the following should work.

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(.[,c(2:4)] >= 0.5) > 0)
```

---

We can also use `apply` version which would be slow for larger datasets

```
df[apply(df[2:4] >= 0.5, 1, any), ]
```